# Extracting element IDs of required forms in selenium/python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, getattribute

I'm crawling this page (https://boards.greenhouse.io/reddit/jobs/4330383) using Selenium in Python and am looping through all of the required fields using:

`required = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("[aria-required=true]")`.

The problem is that I can't view each element's `id`. The command `required[0].id` (which is the same as `driver.find_element_by_id("first_name").id` returns a long string of alphanumeric characters and hyphens – even though the `id` is `first_name` in the HTML. Can someone explain to be why the `id` is being changed from `first_name` to this string? And how can I view the actual `id` that I'm expecting?

Additionally, what would be the simplest way to reference the associated label mentioned right before it in the HTML (i.e. "First Name " in this case)? The goal is to loop through the `required` list and be able to tell what each of these forms is actually asking the user for.

Thanks in advance! Any advice or alternatives are welcome, as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is almost good. All you need to do is use the .get_attribute() method to get your id's:

```
required = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("[aria-required=true]")
for r in required:
    print(r.get_attribute("id"))
```

Answer (score 1):

`driver.find_element_by_id("first_name")` returns a web element object.
In order to get a web element attribute value like `href` or `id` -  `get_attribute()` method should be applied on the web element object.
So, you need to change your code to be

```py
driver.find_element_by_id("first_name").get_attribute("id")
```

This will give you the `id` attribute value of that element

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer my second question (*"How to reference the element's associated label?"*) since I just figured it out using the `find_element_by_xpath()` method in conjunction with the `.get_attribute("id")` solutions mentioned in the previous answers:

```
ele_id = driver.find_element_by_id("first_name").get_attribute("id")
label_text = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//label[@for="{}"]'.format(ele_id)).text
```